# importing error in pytorch lightning bolts

Tags: python, machine-learning, import, importerror, pytorch-lightning

I have installed `pytorch_lightning` and `pl_bolts` using the commands below:

1. `!pip install pytorch-lightning --upgrade`
2. `!pip install pytorch-lightning-bolts`

However, when I import `pl_bolts`, I get the following error:

```
ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import pl_bolts

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pl_bolts/callbacks/data_monitor.py in
4 import torch
5 from pytorch_lightning import Callback, LightningModule, Trainer
----> 6 from pytorch_lightning.loggers import LightningLoggerBase, TensorBoardLogger, WandbLogger
7 from pytorch_lightning.utilities import rank_zero_warn
8 from pytorch_lightning.utilities.apply_func import apply_to_collection

ImportError: cannot import name 'LightningLoggerBase' from 'pytorch_lightning.loggers' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/loggers/init.py)
```

My current environment has the following package versions:

- Python version: 3.10.11
- Torch version: 2.0.0+cu118
- Torchvision version: 0.15.1+cu118
- Pytorch-lightning version: 2.0.2
- Pytorch-lightning-bolts version: 0.6.0.post1

The import does not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, you need to use PyTorch Lightning 1.9 to use Lightning Bolts at the moment. Feel free to reach out on Discord if you would like to contribute by upgrading Bolts to the latest Lightning version.